# "Generating equivalence relations" in David Spivak's "Category Theory for Sciences"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I'm reading "Category Theory for Sciences" by David I. Spivak where I found the following proposition which I try to understand:
[image]

Shouldn't there be **S** instead of **S'** in the last sentence?

If there was **S** then I could interpret it as some kind of minimal equivalence relation containing the elements of non-necessarily-equivalence relation R. Otherwise I don't get it.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are correct.

Comment: Yes, it's a typo. You can tell because it wouldn't make grammatical sense otherwise. $S'$ is a bound variable in the second-to-last sentence, so it wouldn't make sense to refer to it outside of that sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that last sentence is a typo, and should read,

> The relation $S$ is called the equivalence relation generated by $R$.

The proof of the proposition is presumably to let $S$ be the intersection of all equivalence relations $S'$ containing $R$. That there is at least one equivalence relation is obvious because $X\times X$ is an equivalence relation which contains $R$. You can also check that if $\{S_\alpha\}$ is an arbitrary collection of equivalence relations, then $\bigcap_\alpha S_\alpha$ is also an equivalence relation.

If $S'$ is any equivalence relation containing $R$, then by definition of $S$, $S\subset S'$.

Comment: You actually need to check that an arbitrary intersection of equivalence relations is still an equivalence relation, not just a finite intersection. But this is not really any harder.

Comment: @M.Sperling, thanks for the comment, I added it into the post.